# CloudFront and API Gateway service on same domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

I want to:

- Distribute the static part of the website (html, css, js) on my domain www.example.com.
- Put API Gateway services on my domain under a folder, www.example.com/v1.

How do I accomplish this?

In route 53, from what I understand I can only point to **one** cloudfront distribution, so I am choosing my S3/CloudFront enabled bucket.

So, the end result should be, in order of priority/mapping:

- www.example.com/v1/* <-> API Gateway <-> Lambda <-> DynamoDB
- www.example.com/* <-> CloudFront <-> S3 bucket contents

In what way can I achieve this? And if not, what are my alternatives since I need to bend to the same origin principle requirement in web browsers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You would setup CloudFront with two origins, S3 and API Gateway, and configure CloudFront to use the API Gateway origin for all requests that start with `/v1`

Comment: Yes, the problem is that my APIs are not showing up in the list, when adding an origin. AM I missing a step here after my API Gateway services has been deployed?

Comment: What list? You would need to add it as a custom origin.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Some resources appears in an auto completion list, my APIs were not. Pasting it in worked. Thank you.

Comment: Has anyone seen decent documentation / tutorial on this? My API origin is not configured right and I haven't found any references.

Comment: @Wrench by pasting it in, what did you paste in exactly? restApiId? service?

Comment: It's the invokeURL https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudfront-distribution/

Comment: make sure the path uses a wildcard. E.g. /v1/*